# can anyone explain How Sorted function is working here especially that second part " -items[0] "

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, dictionary, hashmap

```
# code to print elements in a list on the basis of frequency they occurr
class Solution:
def frequencySort(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    hashMap = {}
    res = []
    # getting the frequency
    for i in nums:
        if i in hashMap:
            hashMap[i] = hashMap.get(i) + 1
        else:
            hashMap[i] = 1
    # sorting on the basis of value in dictionary
    hashMap = sorted(hashMap.items(), key=lambda item: (item[1], -item[0]))

    for k,v in hashMap:
        res.extend([k]*v)
    
    return res
```

> this code returns a list on the basis of the frequency the element appears in the list
> it stores the count of each element
> then sorts the elements on the basis of their frequency
> and then append the elements the time they appear

Comment: I suggested printing the list `sorted(item[1], -item[0] for item in hashMap.items())` so you can "see" what's happening.

Comment: Also note that `collections.Counter(seq).most_common()` appears to do the same thing as your `frequencySort(seq)`.